# MFSideMenu Delegate Method not called from HomeViewController Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates

I had Implemented MFSideMenu in my Application to display left side slide in-out menu.Now I would like to recognise swipe in and swipe out (i.e. Sidemenu open or closed status)by creating delegate method in ThirdParty class MFSideMenuContainerViewController.h as

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MFSideMenuShadow.h"

@class MFSideMenuContainerViewController;
@protocol MFSideMenuContainerViewControllerViewDelegate <NSObject>   //define delegate protocol

- (void)swipedLeftSidemenu:(BOOL)isOpen;  //define delegate method to be implemented within another class
@end //end protocol

@interface MFSideMenuContainerViewController : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

//custom delegate property
@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MFSideMenuContainerViewControllerViewDelegate> delegate1; 
@end
```

and then call delegate method from below method of MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m

```
- (void)openLeftSideMenuCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
   if(!self.leftMenuViewController) return;

   //call as below 
   [self.delegate1 swipedLeftSidemenu:YES];

   //below is default thirdparty implementation
   [self.menuContainerView bringSubviewToFront:[self.leftMenuViewController view]];
   [self setCenterViewControllerOffset:self.leftMenuWidth animated:YES completion:completion];

 }
```

Delegate method used in another viewcontroller class to detect side menu is open or closed for that I had implemented below code

in DemoViewController.h file

```
#import "MFSideMenuContainerViewController.h"
@interface DemoViewController : UIViewController <ContactViewDelegate,MFSideMenuContainerViewControllerViewDelegate>
```

in DemoViewController.m file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];

   MFSideMenuContainerViewController *vc2 = [[MFSideMenuContainerViewController alloc] init];
   vc2.delegate1 = self;
}

//DelegateMethod Implementation
-(void)swipedLeftSidemenu:(BOOL)isOpen
{
   if(isOpen)
   {
     // code is here if side menu is open by swiping right
   }
   else
   {
     // code is here if side menu is closed by swiping left
   }
}
```

Now I having issue is above method in DemoViewController.m file is never called although sidemenu can be swiped left or right.Can any one guide how I can detect side menu is open or close from DemoViewController class? Or Why this method is never called ?

My appdelegate.m files having below code only

```
    @interface AppDelegate ()

    @end

    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (DemoViewController *)demoController
    {
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

       DemoViewController *demoController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DemoViewController"];

       return demoController;
    }

    - (UINavigationController *)navigationController
    {
       return [[UINavigationController alloc]
        initWithRootViewController:[self demoController]];
    }

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
       self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
       UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

       SideMenuViewController *leftMenuViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SideMenuViewController"];

       MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController
                                                containerWithCenterViewController:[self navigationController]
                                                leftMenuViewController:leftMenuViewController
                                                rightMenuViewController:nil];

      self.window.rootViewController = container;
      [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

      return YES;
   }
```

Comment: please share your AppDelegate.h n .m codes

Comment: @AbhinandanPratap please check as I only define rootviewcontroller from appdelegate.

Answer (score 0):

Update your code In your AppDelegate.h file

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(strong,nonatomic)ViewController *viewController;
@property(strong,nonatomic)LeftSideViewController *leftSideViewController;
@property(strong,nonatomic)MFSideMenuContainerViewController *container;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

and in your AppDelegate.m file update your code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.container = [MFSideMenuContainerViewController containerWithCenterViewController:self.navigationController leftMenuViewController:_leftSideViewController rightMenuViewController:nil];


    self.window setRootViewController:_container];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of delegate method I had replaced it with NotoficationCenter Observer method and that code is as below :

STEP-1

in ThirdParty class MFSideMenuContainerViewController.m as

```
- (void)openLeftSideMenuCompletion:(void (^)(void))completion
{
   if(!self.leftMenuViewController) return;
   NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"isOpen": @"1"};
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"swipeClassDelegateMethod" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

   //below is default thirdparty implementation

   [self.menuContainerView bringSubviewToFront:[self.leftMenuViewController view]];
   [self setCenterViewControllerOffset:self.leftMenuWidth animated:YES completion:completion];
}
```

STEP-2 :  then I called below code from my DemoViewController.m file viewDidLoad method

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(swipeClassDelegateMethod:)name:@"swipeClassDelegateMethod" object:nil];

STEP-3 : Finally I implemented this function with necessary code as below in same DemoViewController.m class

-(void)swipeClassDelegateMethod:(NSNotification*)notification
{
}